# How to tell if XML Sitemap is correct?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I have installed the XML Sitemap module, and enabled the xmlsitemap_menu sub-module.  I found how to add the main menu to the sitemap (via this site - no thanks to the module's documentation). When I go to the XML Sitemap admin page, it lists `mysite/sitemap.xml` as having 91 links and 1 pages. Shouldn't the page count be higher?  Also, I would like to view the generated output, but when I click the `sitemap.xml` link, all I get is a table with link to the front page.

How can I see the actual XML or sitemap output?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you have the content types that you want in your sitemap, you can enable `xmlsitemap_node`.  After enabling, visit each content types configuration page and select "Include" under the xmlsitemap tab.

After setting each content type, you can check the Included/Excluded status for all content types under the xmlsitemap module config page.

Once that is complete, you can run cron manually to regenerate the sitemap links.  Check `www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml` to view the newly generated sitemap.

Comment: I have done all that, but it looks like `mysite/sitemap.xml` basically just says that the file exists.  I can't see what kind of map it's reporting to Google or whatnot. I have rebuilt links, run cron, cleared the cache, and even disabled the "include a stylesheet for humans" setting.

Comment: Is it possible that the server must be connected to the Internet in order to properly build the sitemap? My dev box is on our internal (unplugged) network. I just migrated a snapshot to production, and after clicking the "Rebuild Links" button there, everything shows up.  Maybe the module has to look at the site from outside?

Comment: The server doesn't have to be connected to the internet, it could be any number of things.  It may be that you have to set `$base_url` in settings.php - glad you got it working on a live site though